# signed avx512 vnni multiplication

Tags: x86-64, avx512

I am trying to use AVX512 VNNI instructions to perform signed int8 multiplication. It appears that the instructions only support signed int8 multiplied with an unsigned int8 operand. I wonder what's the best way to multiply two signed int8 operands. Shifting one of the int8 to unsigned and then shifting the result back works but for the purpose of this question doesn't count.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't count"? Even if that's the best way to do it? Also, you need to clarify what kind of output you expect: Individual 16bit values, summed up values, truncated, ...?

Comment: Anything that works should be considered as one of the options for best performance.  The details matter; since there isn't an instruction that does exactly what you want, the best choice will depend on the surrounding code / use-case.